# How to decrypt password which is stored in mongodb using org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-framework-beans

Password is stored in mongoDB using org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoderdecrypt.
As this API stores password in DB in encrypted format even I store same password it encrypt differently and stores in DB. Now my question is How can I compare entered password is already stored in DB or not.How can I achieve my goal can you please explain?

Comment: you shouldn't be able to decrypt passwords. In a standard set up your passwords will be stored as one-way (salted) hashes in your db and what you do when a user tries to log in is to perform the same hashing and compare to the password hash in the db to confirm they have typed in the same password.

Comment: ok. As this API stores password in DB in encrypted format even I store same password it encrypt differently and stores in DB. Now my question is  How can I compare entered password is already stored in DB or not.So asked question about decryption. How can I achieve my goal can you please explain?

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place. That said, look at the Spring documentation. If it has methods to save passwords, it will also have methods to check entered passwords against stored ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found that I cannot exactly match the password but here is workaround
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String enteredNewPassword =  // Password entered by user
String dbPassword       =  // Load hashed DB password

if (passwordEncoder.matches(enteredNewPassword, dbPassword)) {
    //Password is Already exists in db need to store new password
} else {
    // new Password
}
```